# Show dynamic content in an ASP.NET gridview using bootstrap popovers

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, popover

using asp.net / c# I have a gridview that works fine. I would like to have a "i" icon next to my ID field that shows additional information about that item (columns I can't fit in the gridview due to width restrictions).

I am using bootstrap for my "look and feel" and the popovers work fine with static content.

How do I get dynamic content into the data-content field of my  controls?

So far I have this:

```
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ItemID" SortExpression="ItemID">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ItemID")%> '/>

                    <a href="#" rel="popover"
                        data-original-title='<%# Eval("ItemID")%>'
                        data-content='<a href="????">Item Details</a>'>

                        <i class='icon-info-sign'></i>

                    </a>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

I'm assuming though that this will never work and I'll have to do this in the codebehind with a findcontrol?

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

why are you trying to add a link inside a link? I had the same problem just now and what I did and worked was:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText='Descrição'>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a href="#" rel="popover" class="popoverDescricao"
            data-original-title='Descrição Completa'
            data-content='<%# Eval("YourDataContent")%>'>
            <i class='icon-info-sign'></i>
        </a>
    </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: I wanted the popover box that appears to contain a link. But the trigger is a link also hence the "link inside a link"